# Nginx 403 Error for Js Css and Images

Tags: nginx

I am trying doing a magento installation on a server. Here is my Vhost file.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ## SSL directives might go here
    server_name development.magento.in ; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/devcode/;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    location / {
            index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
            try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
            expires 365d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
            rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
    }

    location /app/                { deny all; }
    location /includes/           { deny all; }
    location /lib/                { deny all; }
    location /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location /shell/              { deny all; }
    location /downloader/         { deny all; }
    location /cron.php            { deny all; }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
       rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
   }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
            return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    # serve static files directly

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|txt)$ {
        # root /var/www/devcode/skin/; # I tried to added to this also but never worked
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
    }

location ~ \.php$
{
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
}

}
```

So by this config Nginx shows **403 for Css and js and Images**. The funny part is if I remove the section for serving static files it show **404**. 
I have tried all the posts on Stackoverflow.
Here is how my Media and skin directory permissions looks like

```
drwxr-xr-x. 23 nginx  nginx   4096 Mar 22 14:32     media
drwxr-xr-x.  5 nginx  nginx   4096 Mar 13 03:45     skin
```

Any help or hint will be highly respected!

---

**EDIT**

My New Conf File goes like that:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    ## SSL directives might go here
    server_name development.magento.in ; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
    root /var/www/devcode/;

    index   index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    include        /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/development.access.log ;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/development.error.log ;

    client_max_body_size 2M;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/  /index.php?$args;   #@handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
            expires 365d; ## Assume all files are cachable
    }

    if ($request_uri = /index.php) {
            rewrite ^ http://$host? permanent;
    }

    location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|var)/ { internal; }
    location /var/export/ { internal; }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
       rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
            return 404;
    }

    # serve static files directly
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|txt)$ {
        access_log        off;
        expires           30d;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

 }
```

Now My previous issue is Fixed. But now I can't get My site running. I have checked access.log it says `HTTP 200 OK` but index.php is not receiving any Request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may simply use [alias](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias) directive for static files:

```
location /skin {
    alias /var/www/devcode/skin;
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;
}
```

or more explicitly

```
location /skin/ {
    alias /var/www/devcode/skin/;
    access_log        off;
    expires           30d;
}
```

(see the forward slash difference at the ends..)

Well, you actually could do it with a [root](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#root) directive too, but the last forward slash is too much. See the difference between `alias` and `root` [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,129656,130107#msg-130107). I would still suggest to use `alias` instead of `root` as it has the obvious reasons to serve statics and supported only on `location` level.

**Regardless to my answer**, I would say this configuration looks like coming from apache rewrite logic and not really a well-optimized nginx style overall. You may want to separate your static content as shown above in a different subfolder. Then you also might want to know why [If is Evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil). Instead of rewriting in the `@handler`, you can [try files](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files):

```
location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
    try_files       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

I can't come up with a smarter idea for `deny all`s. However, I would separate the php and static content within a `public` folder and define it as a `root`, by leaving these `deny`s out in the first place. Please note that some of these advices might sound meaningless if they conflict your specific needs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction. can you please be more specific about when you say `configuration looks like coming from apache rewrite logic and not really a well-optimized nginx style overall` and can give me some link so that I can learn that approach

Comment: for `deny all` [wiki.nginx.org] suggest following config `location ^~ /(app|includes|lib|media/downloadable|pkginfo|report/config.xml|var)/ { internal; }

  location /var/export/ { internal; }`
I'd like to tell you that I have solved the issue. But after that I see no request on my index.php. When I hit the site access.log shows HTTP status 200 but index.php don't execute.
I am updating new Vhost file in my Question

Comment: yeah, the try files in my `@handler` is to show it to you instead of your `rewrite` and won't work. you have to figure out how to merge/combine all these `location / {}`, `if ($request_uri = /index.php) {}`, `location ~ .php/ {}` and `location @handler {}` by yourself. If the answer solves your question, could you please mark it as selected.